# Removing UIImageView and getting the memory back (my memory is leaking)

Tags: objective-c, memory, uiimageview, erase

I am making a simple drawing application, but a have problems with memory. After a few minutes using it, it just collapse, it makes the iPad very slow.

The lines the user create drawing are made of a UIImageView of 2x2 pixel, so it's this UIImageView is created several times:

```
UIImageView*dibujo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-1,y-1,2,2)];
dibujo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pixelde2po2.png"];
tagdedibujo=tagdedibujo+1;
dibujo.tag=tagdedibujo;
[self.view addSubview:dibujo];
```

And it's being erased in this way:

```
    for (int aa=ultimotag+1; aa<=tagdedibujo; aa++) {
    //NSLog(@"destruyendo: %i", aa);
    UIImageView*dibujo1 = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:aa];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        dibujo1.alpha=0;
    }];

}

[self performSelector:@selector(matardibujo) withObject:(self) afterDelay:(0.51)];
   ultimotag=tagdedibujo;




-(void) matardibujo{
for (int aa=ultimotag+1; aa<=tagdedibujo; aa++) {
    [[self.view viewWithTag:aa] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

}

Even after erasing de draw (matardibujo) i don't get the memory back. Even it grows. So i think the erasing part is the one that's messing here.

I would preciate your help, i'm kind of new in this. Thanks :).

Comment: If you don't use ARC, after `[self.view addSubview:dibujo];` insert `[dibujo release];`

Comment: I disabled ARC to try this, but nothing, it's acting the same. After erasing the draw, the memory usage it`s even higher than before erasing it.

Comment: Are you sure that the views are correctly removed from superview? I see that you have a delay of 0.51 to perform the selector, and it should be fine for a simple view removal (you must wait that the animation finish before remove the view, and your animation time is 0.50)...but is it enough for more views animated one after another in a cycle? How many views are you animating in that cycle? try to increase the delay, or better use [UIView animateWithDuration: animations: completion:] (and in the completion call the performselector *on main thread* only on the last animation)

Comment: Or try to completely remove your performselector and change the UIView animation line with this: `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ dibujo1.alpha=0; } completion:^{ [dibujo1 removeFromSuperview]; }];`

Comment: you are right, the views wasn't correctly removed. The problem is that when a try what you write on your second comment it gives me this bug: incompatible block pointer types sending 'void(^)(void)' to parameter 'void(^)(bool)

Comment: The first block has nothing passed to it. The second has a BOOL sent to it to tell you whether the animation was completed or cancelled. Use `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations: ^{//animations here} completion: ^(BOOL finished){//completion handling here}];`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the finished param :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you replace `dibujo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pixelde2po2.png"];` with the following line of code to see if it resolves your issue?

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pixelde2po2" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```